# CKEditor 4.6 sometimes strips <span> attributes without following configuration

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have some weird behavior from my CKEditor 4.6, where it sometimes strips an attribute from a span.

I have a custom plugin that adds @mentions, and inserts a span used as placeholder for later parsing server-side, like this:

```
var placeholder = '<span class="mention" contenteditable="false" mention-id="' + clickedSuggestion.Id + '">@' + clickedSuggestion.Title + '</span>';
var mentionElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(placeholder);
editor.insertElement(mentionElement);
```

In my configuration I have allowed those elements:

```
editor.config.extraPlugins += ',mention'; // my custom plugin
editor.config.extraAllowedContent = { span: { classes: 'mention', attributes: 'contenteditable' } };
```

Now what happens sometimes (maybe 1 out of 20 times) is that the mention-id attribute gets stripped away.

```
// what sometimes happens
<span class="mention" contenteditable="false">@foo</span>

// usual output
<span class="mention" contenteditable="false" mention-id="bar">@foo</span>
```

I realize that there's no mention-id in the extraAllowedContent configuration, and that would be the logical cause of the issue. But on the other hand it works great the majority of times!

I don't understand why the attribute isn't stripped away all the time?
Thanks!

EDIT: So it seems extraAllowedContent isn't applied when using editor.insertElement(), so that rules the bad configuration out. But there is still an attribute disappearing during the createFromHtml or the insertElement call.